# How to get a PersistentList from a Cons?

Tags: clojure

I am loading forms from a file using slurp, read, and cons'ing them together to recursively read all forms into a collection. Then wish to pass this into scriptjure's (js [& forms]) function, which expects a (list?), but (cons) gives me a Cons classed-object. How may I convert (class (cons 1 '(2 3 4 5))) to be IPersistentList? Thanks!

Comment: scriptjure really shouldn't be demanding a list in the first place. It should accept a seq instead. I had a look at its source to see about sending a pull request, but it's pretty messy.

Comment: Yeah... actually I found it is not intended to be used for "many" forms at all, but just little uses of JS within html. But I really do not like the JavaDot syntax of ClojureScript, and it is a bit large and very difficult to include into a project (the REPL gets stuck) - and ClojureJS is not loading at all with Clojure 1.3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(apply list x)` to create a `list` from sequence `x` :

```
user=> (class (apply list (cons 1 '(2 3 4 5 6))))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Alternatively, if you start with a list and then `conj` forms onto it, you'll end up with a list:

```
user=> (class (conj (list 1 2 3) 4))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

No need for `cons` in this case since `conj`, given a list, returns a list.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I had a feeling to learn this 'apply' thing I have been seeing everywhere. I am liking the 'conj' version - however I do end up with nil as first or last element, which must be in my code logic. Thanks!